# Safari не принимает строку в обратных скобках (`)

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

Ошибка SyntaxError: Invalid character: '`' хотя в других браузерах все норм.

```
$('.results_block').html(
  `<div class="form category">
    <h4>Материал:</h4>
    <div class="col-xs-12 onem">
    <p class="list_member form_1 col-xs-8">Изготовитель</p>
    <span class="col-xs-4 form_1_q">` + selected_maker +  `</span>`
);
```

Comment: в какой версии сафари осуществлялась проверка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, [не понимает](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8). Не используй их, либо используй [бабель](https://babeljs.io).

А ещё, это не скобка.

Comment: что за бабель ?

Comment: Транспайлер js. https://babeljs.io

Comment: @Qwertiy, начиная с 9 версии [вполне понимает](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility)